# Detecting a data type of response from API

Tags: swift

I have a class like that

```
class MyClass {

    var data : Any

    init(data: Any) {

        self.data = data
 
    }
}
```

And Json response from API

```
var data : Any
                        
  if let dataStr = JSON["data"] as? String {
       data = dataStr
  } else if let dataInt = subJSON["data"] as? Int {
       data = dataInt
  }

  let dt = MyClass(data: data) <- I get `Variable 'data' used before being initialized`
```

So JSON["data"] can be both String or Int. How can I handle it?

Comment: It's because if `JSON["data]` is not a `Int`, not a `String` (or not present), `data` won't be initialized. You are missing a `else` case. Not related : Don't need Codable? Also, does it matter to have both? Why not keeping internally only one kind and do the transformation when parsing?

Comment: @Larme Can you write an answer explaining your idea, please?

Comment: `class MyClass { var data: String }` and `if let dataStr ... as? String { data = dataStr } else if dataInt ... as? Int { data = "\(dataInt)" } else { data = "" //Can this even happen? }`?

Comment: `Any` as a common type for `String` and `Int` is a very bad and *unswifty* practice. Use a protocol or an enum with associated types. And drop `SwiftyJSON` in favor of `Codable`.

Comment: @vadian a small example about protocol or enum as an answer would be very helpful as I am trying to learn more

Comment: Since your class property is of type Any you don't need to cast it first and you can simply do `if let data = JSON["data"] { dt = MyClass(data: data) }`. But this is a bad solution to start with to have a property of type `Any` so I think you should rethink your design.